# CRTP: why a difference between getting a nested type and nested method of the derived class?

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

The base class in the CRTP pattern can access the member functions of the derived class, but it can't access a nested type in the derived class.

Why this difference?

To illustrate, consider the following piece of code:

```
template<typename Derived>
struct crtp_base
{
    void crtp_method() { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this).method(); } // compiles

    using crtp_type = typename Derived::type; // doesn't compile
};

struct X : public crtp_base<X>
{
    void method() {}

    using type = int;
};

int main()
{

}
```

`crtp_type` causes a compilation error, while `crtp_method` compiles fine, although both attempt to access something defined in the `Derived` class. What is the C++ specification that explains that difference?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: error: no type named 'type' in 'X'. Here is the [full program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc8c236719fd755a).

Comment: Why do you use `static_cast<>`?  Just calling `this->method();` compiles fine (gcc 6.3.0, clang 3.8)

Comment: @AdrianW Could you please send across a compiling code snippet?

Comment: Here you are: https://godbolt.org/g/vPn2JX

Comment: It's because it doesn't call the function, but it stops from compiling when it instantiates it: https://godbolt.org/g/nKPwgm

Comment: Ah, got it, thank you. `method()` is only declared in the derived class and therefore will not be known in the base class `crtp_base<X>`. Declaring as abstract virtual virtual method in `crtp_base` fixes the problem. This is IMHO stll better than `static_cast`. Updated example here: https://godbolt.org/g/VVwuD9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference here is that instantiation of method happens only when you actually use it while instantiation of `crtp_base` happens at `public crtp_base<X>` where type `X` is still incomplete. The workaround would be to use type traits:

```
template<typename x_Target>
struct Trait;

template<typename Derived>
struct crtp_base
{
    void crtp_method() { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this).method(); }

    using crtp_type = typename Trait<Derived>::type;
};

struct X;

template<>
struct Trait<X>
{
    using type = int;
};

struct X : public crtp_base<X>
{
    void method() {}

    using type = Trait<X>::type;
};
```